# SteamBot.exe don't appear in SteamBot/Bin/Release

Tags: linux, git, mono, steambot

I am trying to install steam bot on Centos 6.7.
I have installed NuGet2, mono, steam, I have done all, what was said in [Jessecar96 Installation Guide](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot/wiki/Setting-Up-SteamBot-on-Linux).

I have compiled Nuget, mono latest release, but nothing happens. 
When I am trying to run SteamBot.exe, which should be on Bin/Release folder, it shows me error, that file don't exist. Maybe I have done something wrong?

1. Installed mono - compiled it.
2. Installed Nuget2 - compiled.
3. After that i thought that i have not installed SteamBot.
4. Installed SteamBot, cloned it.
5. After that I removed git, git-clone.
6. Again installed and compilet git.
7. running `cd ~/SteamBot/Bin/Release/SteamBot.exe` and I get error, that file doesn't exist.

What is this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay multiple issues here.

After cloning the repo you need to compile the source it contains.
By default the output is to /Bin/Debug/
Even assuming that you do those two steps cd is for changing directories and you would do `mono ~/SteamBot/Bin/Debug/SteamBot.exe` instead.